# Standard for programming 'beautiful' code in Java?

Tags: java, coding-style

I'm reading some books about coding standard in Java.
I always loved beautiful and clean code.

But there are some things that bother me. For example, a method name should start with a lowercase word, and if it has a second word, it should be start with a uppercase character. But the standard for variables is the same thing. I think this is a little confusing.

So I'm asking you guys, what's your coding standard in Java?
Like:

1. How do you name objects, methods, classes, *etc*.
2. If you have more than one object from same class, how do you name the second one?
3. If you have one object in the argument of a method and you have another object from the same class inside this method, how you do name both of them?
4. What is the best trade-off for performance/code beauty, a lot of small methods, or some longer methods?
5. Feel free to say something more. =)

Comment: *Always loved beautiful clean code* - with Java thats impossible ... kidding :)

Comment: take all the answers suggesting Java code convention with a grain of salt.  It is *very* hard to have beautiful looking Java code using the default convention.  I've seen C code so nice I took screenshots and printed it.  I've hardly ever seen Java code that looks nice: try to instantiate a generified collection and tell me if it can look "nice" (Java is so verbose you can't really have nice-looking code).  Note that I **do** suggest following Java coding convention: but you'll end up with ugly looking code.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: Well considering that C doesn't have generics the comparison is a bit flawed. And if I compare C++ templates to Java generics.. no, don't really see much difference. At least Java does have an official coding convention.. if C had one that would've saved many headaches.

Comment: @Voo: one thing that actually saves even more headaches is Google's "Go" language: there the indentation and bracket position are forced by the language specs and there's a tool doing the formatting automatically (and IDE will force the indent/brackets positions too).  No more silly flamewars *"brackets on the same line as the if"* or "4 spaces or 2 spaces indents" etc.  :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Mostly following the [Java code convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf).
2. I try to not make it matter what kind of class an object is. If I for instance have five different strings, the name of each variable should describe what information/content the variable represents, and not that is is a string.
3. I find it often silly to try coming up with variations of a variable just because it exists both as a method argument and a class variable. I mostly use the same name with this syntax `this.theVariable = theVariable`
4. A method should be as short as possible: as few lines as possible, and as few nested levels as possible (i.e. max one if-statement, and not ifs inside ifs etc.)
5. [Robert Martin's Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) is highly recommended!

Comment: Well I'm not too sure about 4 as a general rule. Obviously a large unreadable junk of code is bad, but I've seen the opposite and it was extremely hard to read the code. I try to split the code into parts that make semantically sense.

Comment: @Voo: naturally, nothing should be overdone. There is no point breaking down your code so that every function only consists of a single line. Still, if you end up having functions spanning several lines (I guess there is no good answer for what is to be considered "several" - it might be 5, 10, or 20 or even more, completely depending on the situation), there's a pretty good chance you could do some meaningful refactoring - either into more functions, or even split things up into several classes.

Comment: As of Aug 2020, this is the link: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Just to address one specific point, because it's one I commonly see people doing horrific things with:

> If you have more than one object from same class, how do you name the second one?

By their purpose, surely. If you have two different objects of the same class, you must be using them for different purposes, so name it after that purpose. I think all of these examples would be pretty self-explanatory to most readers:

```
public void copyAddresses(Customer source, Customer destination) {


public void sendMessage(Mailbox sender, Mailbox recipient) {


public void changeContactCompany(User contact, Company from, Company to) {


public void eatWatermelon(Bowl servingBowl, Bowl bowlForSeedSpitting) {
```

or whatever... you get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

You should start with the official [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

They will explain why code conventions are needed, different conventions and, what your question seems to be about, [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367). They add various examples too.

Comment: and if you're using a nice IDE such as [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), it will help you very much. It will organize imports in the order they should appear, ident code based on the limit line, warn you about some bad practices, and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best trade-off for
>   performance/code beauty, a lot of
>   small methods, or some longer methods?

"Premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth

Remember:

1. Make it **work**.
2. Make it **right**.
3. Make it **fast**.

You should only worry about performance if it is warranted; if the current code is too slow to meet requirements.

In that case you should find the 'hot-spots' and optimize those. Check if performance is good enough. If not, repeat.

Comment: +1 a very valid point to keep in mind.

Comment: That's a very brief, out of context (and widely misinterpreted) snippet of Knuth's actual quote.

Comment: @Robert_Harvey: can you elaborate on that please? I always heard it in this context and I want to make sure I will not spread this further if its wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @c_maker: this blog post will perhaps give you a bit more context around Knuth's quote (or this _part_ of the quote, as it really is): http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/09/performance-and-optimization-isnt-evil/

Answer (score 2):

Well since most of these are easily googled I will add my own standard Java naming practices:

**I usually suffix the name of classes of what they extend or implement.**
In other words Spring MVC controllers are suffixed with "Controller". This makes it easy in Eclipse to do a Crtl-Shift-R *Controller.

Second if I find I need to aggregate a whole bunch of **static methods in a class I usually suffix that class with "Utils"**. I got this from Apache Commons and has just stuck.

Finally derived methods that do special expensive stuff and are transient I avoid calling them getXXX. The reason is to avoid problems with serializers.

Answer (score 1):

Look here at the [official guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)