# Organizing members of a class java

Tags: java

am wondering, what is the right way to organize the members of a class in java? Should we start with the public members and then the private or the private members first?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5210844/647772

Comment: There isn't a mandatory norm for that. You can do what you want. But I always use this order for better clarity: Attributes - Constructors - Destructors - Public functions - Private functions

Comment: See the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141855.html#3043), especially '3.1.3 Class and Interface Declarations'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [which order is better for field declaring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791861/which-order-is-better-for-field-declaring)

Comment: @Napsteur You *can* but you *shouldn't*. Code is read 80% of the time. Don't make it harder than necessary for the reader.

Comment: Some parts of those conventions, written 15 years ago, seem a little outdated...

Comment: For example: http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/java-coding-conventions-considered.html it is a bit of a rant but makes a few valid points.

Comment: @Napsteur.. And there is no such thing as `Destructors` in Java.

Comment: @Rohit: there is destructors. The syntax is `public void finalize(){}`

Comment: @Napsteur.. [They are not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171952/is-there-a-destructor-for-java) <-- Click.. Also see: - [finalizers - wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalizer)

Comment: @assylias - He makes a couple of valid points (indentation levels and text width), but he degenerates into irrelevant nitpicking of the examples ... and I got fed up.  Yea, the old Sun document could be updated, but I don't think there is anyone left with the "standing" to make it happen.  (New coding guidelines are only going to be useful if it is widely accepted.)  So I recommend that people follow the original guidelines tweaked / relaxed to fit in with current practices.

Comment: @StephenC Fair enough. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11792228/829571) makes good points too.

Answer (score 1):

`Member is an interface that reflects identifying information about a single member (a field or a method) or a constructor.` (Oracle official documentation)

So I would suggest that every time it's possible you should make your `fields` private and make `setters and getters` for them. As for the methods - am really not sure if you have to organize them on the fact if they are `public` or `private`